# Combine multiple changes in a DB into 1 transaction

Tags: sql, transactions

I have a simple money transfer application with the initial data:

```
User
 name | balance | hold_balance 
------+---------+--------------
 andy | 500     | 0            
Tx
 id | name | amount | status 
----+------+--------+--------
```

Then, when I transfer with amount 100, my application does the flow:

1. add hold balance: update user.hold_balance to 100

```
User
 name | balance | hold_balance 
------+---------+--------------
 andy | 500     | 100
```

2. insert tx (status: IN_PROGRESS)

```
Tx
 id | name | amount | status     
----+------+--------+------------
 1  | andy | 100    | IN_PROGRESS
```

3. hit 3rd party doing the actual transfer
4. release hold balance: update user.hold_balance back to 0

```
User
 name | balance | hold_balance 
------+---------+--------------
 andy | 500     | 0
```

5. if (3) success then:

   - deduct balance: update user.balance to 500-100 = 400
   - update tx status to OK

```
User
 name | balance | hold_balance 
------+---------+--------------
 andy | 400     | 0            
Tx
 id | name | amount | status 
----+------+--------+--------
 1  | andy | 100    | OK
```

6. or if (3) failed then:

   - only update tx status to FAILED

```
User
 name | balance | hold_balance 
------+---------+--------------
 andy | 500     | 0            
Tx
 id | name | amount | status 
----+------+--------+--------
 1  | andy | 100    | FAILED
```

The problem is above flow is not atomic, whenever an outage occurs in the middle, the data won't be consistent.

How to make the whole DB changes in the flow atomic?
If I use SQL transaction, then where to place the begin and the commit part? or even rollback when needed?

note: the application is a monolith and all the tables reside on the same database.

Comment: This is what transactions do.  Study up on them for the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand how to make those DB changes into 1 transaction, but please note that process (3) can take longer time and even we need to get the response async (by callback, etc) so it's a bit tricky to wrap all of them into 1 transaction